# How to run regressions on multidimensional panel data in R

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, panel, plm

I need to run a regression on a panel data . It has 3 dimensions (Year * Company * Country). For example:

```
============================================
 year | comp | count |  value.x |  value.y
------+------+-------+----------+-----------
 2000 |   A  |  USA  |  1029.0  |  239481   
------+------+-------+----------+-----------
 2000 |   A  |  CAN  |  2341.4  |  129333   
------+------+-------+----------+-----------
 2000 |   B  |  USA  |  2847.7  |  187319   
------+------+-------+----------+-----------
 2000 |   B  |  CAN  |  4820.5  |  392039
------+------+-------+----------+-----------
 2001 |   A  |  USA  |  7289.9  |  429481
------+------+-------+----------+-----------
 2001 |   A  |  CAN  |  5067.3  |  589143
------+------+-------+----------+-----------
 2001 |   B  |  USA  |  7847.8  |  958234
------+------+-------+----------+-----------
 2001 |   B  |  CAN  |  9820.0  | 1029385
============================================
```

However, the R package `plm` seems not able to cope with more than 2 dimension.

I have tried

```
result <- plm(value.y ~ value.x, data = dataname, index = c("comp","count","year"))
```

and it returns error:

```
Error in pdata.frame(data, index) : 
'index' can be of length 2 at the most (one individual and one time index)
```

How do you run regressions when the panel data (individual * time) has more than 1 dimension within "individual"?

---

In case anyone encounters the same situation, I'll put my solutions here:

R seems unable to cope with this situation. And the only thing you can do is to add dummies. If the categorical variables according to which you add dummies contains too much categories, you can try this:

```
makedummy <- function(colnum,data,interaction = FALSE,interation_varnum)
{
  char0 = colnames(data)[colnum]
  char1 = "dummy"
  tmp = unique(data[,colnum])
  valname = paste(char0,char1,tmp,sep = ".")
  valname_int = paste(char0,char1,"int",tmp,sep = ".")
  for(i in 1:(length(tmp)-1))
  {
    if(!interaction)
    {
      tmp_dummy <- ifelse(data[,colnum]==tmp[i],1,0)
    }
    if(interaction)
    {
      index = apply(as.matrix(data[,colnum]),1,identical,y = tmp[i])
      tmp_dummy = c()
      tmp_dummy[index] = data[index,interation_varnum]
      tmp_dummy[!index] = 0
    }
    tmp_dummy <- data.frame(tmp_dummy)
    if(!interaction)
    {
      colnames(tmp_dummy) <- valname[i]
    }
    if(interaction)
    {
      colnames(tmp_dummy) <- valname_int[i]
    }
    data<-cbind(data,tmp_dummy)
  }
  return(data)
}
```

for example:

```
## Create fake data
fakedata <- matrix(rnorm(300),nrow = 100)
cate <- LETTERS[sample(seq(1,10),100, replace = TRUE)]
fakedata <- cbind.data.frame(cate,fakedata)

## Try this
fakedata <- makedummy(1,fakedata)

## If you need to add dummy*x to see if there is any influences of different categories on the coefficients, try this
fakedata <- makedummy(1,fakedata,interaction = TRUE,interaction_varnum = 2)
```

Maybe a little bit verbose here, I didn't polish it. Any advice is welcome. Now you can perform OLS on your data.

Comment: if you want to control for another dimension, simply add a dummy for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is much like these:

- [fixed effects in R: plm vs lm + factor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563595/fixed-effects-in-r-plm-vs-lm-factor/39594688#39594688)
- [Fixed Effects plm package R - multiple observations per year/id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510067/fixed-effects-plm-package-r-multiple-observations-per-year-id/43573731#43573731)

You may not want to create a new dummy, then with dplyr package you can use the `group_indices` function. Although it do not support `mutate`, the following approach is straightforward:

```
fakedata$id <- fakedata %>% group_indices(comp, count)
```

The `id` variable will be your first panel dimension. So, you need to set the plm index argument to `index = c("id", "year")`.

For alternatives you can take a look at this question: [R create ID within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197594/r-create-id-within-a-group/41835891#41835891).

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. But I am still quite confused: is your solution doing a pooling with "comp" and "count" , because the "id" var looks like the Cartesian product of "comp" and "count"? Can the solution fix effects for "comp" and "count" respectively rather than collectively? (I hope I've made myself clear…)

Comment: That's a cartesian product, you are rigth. But I confess I couldn't understand the scond part of you question... Would you like to firm 'A' from 'US' be treated as different of firm 'A' from 'Canada'?

Comment: The econometric model that your answer is suggesting is 'Y_ict = beta * X_ict + f_ic + g_t + h_i + epsilon_ict' , isn't it? (i: firm. c: country. t: year. Y_ict: value.y across i, c, and t. X_ict is similar. f_ic: FE of the id var you create. g_t: time FE. h_i: FE of firms%%as you add factor(firm) in the formula of plm%%). I am just not quite sure if the result it is exactly the same with 'Y_ict = beta * X_ict + j_c + g_t + h_i + epsilon_ict'. (Hope you understand in this way)

Comment: In fact, the 'id' var I suggested treats firms from differents countries as different.

Comment: OK. If the model is exactly what I want, the problem is solved! Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: You can make an OLS on 'Y_ict = beta * X_ict + j_c + g_t + h_i + epsilon_ict', where  j_c + g_t + h_i are dummy variables. It is the same as the within model on 'Y_ict = beta_ic + beta * X_ict + epsilon_ict'. Gujarati's undergrad textbook  has a whole section (The Fixed Effects or Least-Squares Dummy Variable Regression Model) where he discusses the two approaches.

Comment: As of `dplyr 0.7.4` you can use `group_indices` in `mutate`. So OP could do `fakedata <- fakedata %>% mutate(id = group_indices(., comp, count))`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to control for another dimension in a within model, simply add a dummy for it:

`plm(value.y ~ value.x + count, data = dataname, index = c("comp","year"))`

Alternatively (especially for high-dimensional data), look at the `lfe` package which can 'absorb' the additional dimension so the summary output is not polluted by the dummy variable.

Comment: This suggestion did not work for me. The data structure is the same as OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also do:

```
df <-transform(df, ID = as.numeric(interaction(comp, count, drop=TRUE)))
```

And then estimate

```
result <- plm(value.y ~ value.x, data = df, index = ("ID","year"))
```

Answer (score -3):

I think you want to use `lm()` instead of `plm(`). This blog post here discusses what you're after:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-multiple-linear-regression/

for your example I'd imagine it would look something like the following:

```
lm(formula = comp ~ count + year, data = dataname)
```

Comment: OLS is not optimal for panel data since it does not adjust for entity-specific fixed effects nor does it adjust for autocorrelation of the errors. Panel regression (`plm`) is indeed one option that OP can try